# postgreSQL how can I make this work with an aggregation alias?

Tags: postgresql

postgreSQL 9.5.6

How can I make this work using the percent_error alias?

```
SELECT time::date, 
  sum((status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) as not_found,
  sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) as total,
  sum((status='404 NOT FOUND')::int)/sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int)::float as percent_error
  from log
  group by time::date
  having sum((status='404 NOT FOUND')::int)/sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int)::float > 0.01;
```

A query like this work:

```
select species, 
  count(*) as num 
  from animals 
  group by species 
  having num=1;
```

But not this - exactly the same as the first example above except here the last line is using percent_error alias:

```
SELECT time::date, 
  sum((status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) as not_found,
  sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) as total,
  sum((status='404 NOT FOUND')::int)/sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int)::float as percent_error
  from log
  group by time::date
  having percent_error > 0.01;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    time, not_found, total, percent_error
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        time::date, 
        sum((status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) as not_found,
        sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) as total,
        sum((status='404 NOT FOUND')::int)::float / 
             sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) 
             as percent_error
    FROM 
        log
    GROUP BY 
        time::date
    ) AS s0
WHERE 
    percent_error > 0.01 ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=108657696ea785a91a73f486346ff4b1)*

The actual query plan that you get is exactly the same as with your original query; however, the intent is made (in my opinion) much clearer. This is conceptually equivalent to having a `WITH` (although the implementation in PostgreSQL is quite different). The advantages being: more portable (i.e.: implemented by more database engines), more optimizable by the query planner (in PostgreSQL).

---

**Side note**: This query

```
select species, 
  count(*) as num 
  from animals 
  group by species 
  having num=1;
```

doesn't work with postgreSQL 9.6 (nor 8.4). You get the following error (the same as with percent_error):

```
ERROR:  column "num" does not exist
LINE 5:   having num=1;
                 ^
```

It works with `SQLite` and `MariaDB / MySQL`. It doesn't work either with `SQL Server` and `Oracle`. I guess the *not working* is standard SQL; and the working is an extension.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=680b485240eba01f1817911816235b59)*

Answer (score 2):

A "WITH query" (CTE) may be useful for you (see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html - read at least the first paragraph ...)

Here's an example, very close to your situation.  Notice: date_ is the equivalent of time::date in your code:

```
with stats as (
  select
    date_ 
  , sum((status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) as not_found
  , sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) as total
  , sum( (status='404 NOT FOUND')::int) / 
         sum((status='200 OK' OR status='404 NOT FOUND')::int)::float  
    as percent_error
  from log
  group by date_
)
select not_found, total, percent_error
from stats
where percent_error > 0.01 ;
```